# How to rotate map extent differently on each page in map series?

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-series, rotate

I'm a beginner to ArcGIS Pro. For last few weeks, I've been working on creating a map series. So far, I've managed to nail down what needs to be done. However, I'm having difficulties with one particular area: how to rotate the map extent differently on each page in the map series?

I am using ANSI D (22 x 34) landscape page setup for the map series. Each page consists of an individual grid box that is rotated differently.

See few examples here:

[image]

[image]

What I need is both grid boxes to lined up to 90 degrees neatly in order to maximize the extent of their boundary lines within the larger map frame.

Unfortunately, they come from a single Map. So if I rotate one grid box to 90 degrees, this will affect the other pages. There has to be a way to force each page to rotate grid box without affecting the rest of pages.

I'm just guessing, this probably requires a bit of scripting to make my desire a possibility. I'm still learning Python, and I'm not 100% familiar with all geoprocessing tools.

Can you can help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the 'grid boxes' could be considered the **Index Layer** of a **Spatial Map Series**, you could assign/calculate an 'Angle' field (possibly with **Calculate Polygon Main Angle** cartography geoprocessing tool) and use this as the **Rotation** angle under **Optional Fields**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. I edited the grid cells' rotation fields to set their angles to 0 and adjusted accordingly in the page query. I answered my own question, which is a good thing because nobody bothered to answer my question and I didn't wait but continued to investigate the issue until it's resolved to my satisfaction.

Answer (score 0):

I had to figure this out today. You can change the rotation in the Map and then make the Layout. To make a different rotated view, change the rotation in the Map again, and then make a separate Layout. The Layout "view port" rotation is relative to the rotation of the Map at the time that you make the Layout. Hope this helps.